# what does the order in EXPLAIN mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

[8.2.2. EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) gives several examples of EXPLAIN based on successive optimizations of the following SQL query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT tt.TicketNumber, tt.TimeIn,
               tt.ProjectReference, tt.EstimatedShipDate,
               tt.ActualShipDate, tt.ClientID,
               tt.ServiceCodes, tt.RepetitiveID,
               tt.CurrentProcess, tt.CurrentDPPerson,
               tt.RecordVolume, tt.DPPrinted, et.COUNTRY,
               et_1.COUNTRY, do.CUSTNAME
        FROM tt, et, et AS et_1, do
        WHERE tt.SubmitTime IS NULL
          AND tt.ActualPC = et.EMPLOYID
          AND tt.AssignedPC = et_1.EMPLOYID
          AND tt.ClientID = do.CUSTNMBR;
```

Here's the first EXPLAIN they give:

```
table type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows  Extra
et    ALL  PRIMARY       NULL NULL    NULL 74
do    ALL  PRIMARY       NULL NULL    NULL 2135
et_1  ALL  PRIMARY       NULL NULL    NULL 74
tt    ALL  AssignedPC,   NULL NULL    NULL 3872
           ClientID,
           ActualPC
      Range checked for each record (index map: 0x23)
```

Here's the second (after an optimization has been made):

```
table type   possible_keys key     key_len ref         rows    Extra
tt    ALL    AssignedPC,   NULL    NULL    NULL        3872    Using
             ClientID,                                         where
             ActualPC
do    ALL    PRIMARY       NULL    NULL    NULL        2135
      Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)
et_1  ALL    PRIMARY       NULL    NULL    NULL        74
      Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)
et    eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 15      tt.ActualPC 1
```

My question is... what does the order represent? In the first EXPLAIN the `et` column is on top. In the second it'd on bottom. Is there any special significance to this? Are there any inferences that can be made from this?

Comment: I just copy / pasted the query from the example at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html . And I'm not asking about ORDER BY - I'm asking about why EXPLAIN is returning the columns in a certain order.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html):

```
EXPLAIN returns a row of information for each table used in the SELECT statement. 
It lists the tables in the output in the order that MySQL would read them while
processing the statement
```

So I read that as saying, in version 1 `et` is the first table read but after the modification it's not need until the last stage.